# CSP Ineffective headers: Content-Security-Policy, Set-Cookie in Salesforce

Tags: url, cookies, salesforce, content-security-policy, salesforce-communities

The customer reported "Potentially insecure policy; Ineffective headers: Content-Security-Policy, Set-Cookie" for our Community Customer Support portal Site URL.

When I Scan through https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/ it is giving me the below error:

> [image: csp scan error]

But all the directives are provided under Salesforce CSP:

> [image: CSP implemented in SF]

Please let me know the possible solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSP seems to only include the directive "upgrade-insecure-requests". Your customer and the CSP Evaluator rightly finds this to be a very loose policy as it doesn't restrict any sources for script, style or any other fetch directives. They expect a strict policy where you implement other directives that are currently not restricted. The Salesforce tool seems to check that all necessary Salesforce hosts are allowed with your policy and is happy as long as you don't restrict them.